# Compare two files and print all values horizontally if ids are matching?

Tags: python, excel, bash, compare

Hi I have two files as follows:
File1.txt

```
10   A   B  C
10   A   D  K
11   X   Y  Z
10   A   K  B 
11   Y   X  A
```

File2.txt

```
10
11
12
```

The expected output is

```
10 A  B  C  A  D  K  A  K  B
11 X  Y  Z  Y  X  A
```

I tried the command `grep -f File1.txt file2.txt`

But it did not give me all value coming under same id

Comment: Are you using Python or Bash? Or are you intending to find a solution that uses either Python or Bash?

Comment: What is the relevance of File2.txt? Your expected output can be calculated by  File1.txt only.

Comment: @Edric intending to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the line to a dictionary if key is in the second file.
Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("f1.txt") as f1, open("f2.txt") as f2:
    keys = set(f2.read().splitlines())
    for line in f1:
        k, *rest = line.split()
        if k in keys:
            d[k]+=rest


>>> print(*d.items(),sep="\n")
('10', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'K', 'A', 'K', 'B'])
('11', ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'X', 'A'])
```

Comment: this is working...!!! but i need to add empty column also if they are present in between. for example 'A', ' ', 'B'

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] OFS:"")$0
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $1,a[$1]
}
' File1.txt File2.txt
```

Output will be as follows:

```
10 A B C A D K A K B
11 X Y Z Y X A
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                             ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be true for first file1.
  val=$1                             ##Creating variable val with $1 value of it.
  $1=""                              ##Nullify $1 here.
  sub(/^ +/,"")                      ##Substituting initial space with NULL for current line.
  a[val]=(a[val]?a[val] OFS:"")$0    ##Creating array a with index val and keep concatenating its value to it.
  next                               ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){                           ##Checking condition if $1 of current line comes in array a then do following.
  print $1,a[$1]                     ##Printing $1 of current line and value of array a with $1 value.
}
' File1.txt File2.txt                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the relevance of File2.txt here. So you can use this 1 line command if the spacing of the output is not important:

```
sort File1.txt | awk '$1!=key {if (sum) print key sum; key=$1; sum=""} {$1=""; sum=sum $0} END {print key sum}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this:

```
with open("File1.txt") as f1, open("File2.txt") as f2:
    dictf1 = {}
    for i in f1.readlines():
        i = i.split()
        if i[0] in dictf1.keys():
            dictf1[i[0]] += i[1:]
        else:
            dictf1[i[0]] = i[1:]
    for i in f2.readlines():
        if i[:-1] in dictf1.keys():
            print(i[:-1], " ".join(dictf1[i.strip()]))
```

Comment: this is working...!!! but i need to add empty column also if they are present in between. for example  'A', ' ', 'B'

Comment: @Snijesh You want that output as string or list?

Comment: it will be better if the output is like a data-frame or tab delimited text

Comment: @Snijesh Current output is ```10 A B C A D K A K B``` and ```11 X Y Z Y X A```